# PHP URL parameters as a command

Tags: php, oop, url

I want to read the url in php like a command. For example, my htaccess makes it so my url is `www.example.com/index` (Index is really index.php ).

I want it to be so I can execute some code based on the url. SO, if the url was `www.example.com/index/poll/45678` then PHP would read it as, `index -> find poll -> 45678` as a parameter.

Comment: This is called "routing".

Comment: So would something like this: https://github.com/dannyvankooten/PHP-Router or http://blogs.shephertz.com/2014/05/21/how-to-implement-url-routing-in-php/ work?

Comment: Yes, you could implement routing yourself (with or without guides), or use some library like the one you linked above, or use routing component of some framework.

Comment: Or better yet use PHP frameworks.

Comment: minor formatting - not entirely sure why this was in the edit queue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything in the comments worked. It is called "PHP routeing". Google